# Bad practice to return API call and run task in background?

Tags: javascript, node.js, response, api-design

I'm working on a Node project, and in one of the API calls we have the option to reply and then do some more work, or do that work and then reply.

Is it bad practice to start a background task in each API request? Part of the motivation for this is to get the response time down, and then just keep doing any further work in the background. My worry is that the background tasks could build up and then be too much for the process to handle.

I think ideally we might want to put a message onto a message queueing system for workers to process, but that's a bit of overhead.

I know typically error handling would be a concern, but in this case it is okay to just suppress any errors that the background task throws.

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: Imho, asap api response can't be a bad practice. No reason to client waiting if response is already ready to send.

Comment: Any work that might throw an error that requires user action should be done in the same request. Any other work can be pushed onto a queue. While there is a little overhead managing the queue, I think it's worth it.

Comment: This is completely use-case dependent.